# What is the shortest way to write multiline escaped HTML in Pug?

Tags: pug

I m trying to output some HTML code listings in Pug, but with the tag symbols converted to HTML entities (< to & lt; | > to & gt; etc...). So far i have accomplished this by using string interpolation like this

```
pre
 code.
  #{'<li><a href="#">Anchor tag text</a></li>'}
  #{'<li><a href="#">Anchor tag text</a></li>'}
```

Another Example:

```
pre
  code.
    #{'<body>'}
      #{'<div class="divclass">'}
        #{'<h1 class="class1 class2 class3" id="id1">Heading</h1>'}
        #{'<p class="class2 class3 class1" id="id2">Para1</p>'}
      #{'</div>'}
    #{'</body>'}
```

Is there any faster or easier way of achieving the same result? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way would be to store the markup in a variable using a template literal, and then interpolate the variable:

```
-
  const markup =
  `<body>
    <div class="divclass">
      <h1 class="class1 class2 class3" id="id1">Heading</h1>
      <p class="class2 class3 class1" id="id2">Para1</p>
    </div>
  </body>`

pre
  code #{markup}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sean FIrst of all thx a lot for your answer. I found that method of yours a bit tiresome (not to mention that i have to keep track of the variable names, changes are being made constantly and code listings are added inbetween previous ones) so i ended up incorporating the code in a template literal but inside a mixin argument, like this:

```
mixin htmlCode(codeBlock)
  pre.html-icon: code= codeBlock
          
+htmlCode(
`<body>
    <div class="divclass">
      <h1 class="class1 class2 class3" id="id1">Heading</h1>
      <p class="class2 class3 class1" id="id2">Para1</p>
    </div>
</body>`)
```

I also tried to leave the mixin without argument and use the mixin block for the content but it needs interpolation. I can't find a solution for that version.

---

```
//doesn't work as is. It again needs string interpolation on every line
mixin htmlCode
  pre.html-icon: code: block
          
+htmlCode.
  <body>
    <div class="divclass">
      <h1 class="class1 class2 class3" id="id1">Heading</h1>
      <p class="class2 class3 class1" id="id2">Para1</p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

---